# Ejecutar aplicación .NET 4.0 en Raspbian con Mono

Tags: vb.net, raspbian, mono

¿Es posible ejecutar una aplicación .NET 4.0 de windows forms con mono en Raspbian? Cuando intento abrir el setup.exe me da el siguiente error:

```
sudo mono setup.exe

Cannot open assembly 'setup.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image
```

Gracias.

Comment: si no recuerdo mal, para ejecutar desde la consola ponias `mono RUTA` y con sudo

Comment: Si, tras ejecutarlo me lanza el error de arriba